Examples of uncountable second-countable Souslin spaces that are not metrizable
A Hausdorff space $X$ is called Souslin if it is a continuous image of a Polish space.
My question: Is there a uncountable second-countable Souslin space that isn't metrizable? If there is, could please provide some examples?
Thank you for your attention!

Let $X$ be a countable set and $\tau_1$ the discrete topology on $X$, while $\tau_2$ be an Hausdorff, second countable topology which is not metrizable (see Example 100 in the book "Counterexamples in topology"). Now let $Y_1=(X,\tau_1)\sqcup ([0,1],\tau_e)$, and $Y_2=(X,\tau_2)\sqcup ([0,1],\tau_e)$, where by $\sqcup$ I denote the disjoint union and $\tau_e$ denotes the euclidean topology on $[0,1]$. Observe that $Y_2$ is an uncountable, Hausdorff, second countable space which is not metrizable. While $Y_1$ is a Polish space. The identity map from $Y_1$ onto $Y_2$ is a continuous function.
